# Solving $y'' - y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am attemtping to solve $y'' - y = 0$

I come to this solution, by using something like
$\frac{dy}{dx} = p$

So it does
$\frac{dp}{dy} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} - y = 0$

Which gives
$\frac{dp}{dy} \cdot p = y$

After all the transformations, integrating and all, I end up with this expression!

$c_{1}e^{x} = y + \sqrt{y^{2} + c_{2}}$

wow... How am I supposed, from there, to obtain the expected solution, that is,
$y(x) = c_{1}e^{x}+c_{2}e^{-x}$

(Note c1 and c2 are unrelated to the other equation)

Help me please... really.

Thank you

Comment: Hint: Does the auxiliary polynomial, or characteristic polynomial ring a bell? y''-y=0 gives us the polynomial r^2-1=0

Comment: do you just want the solution (in some other manner) or you want to use just this method... :O

Comment: Thank you for your comments but... I am supposed to get it by this solution. I mean... the solutions book arrived to the same thing than I. They just... come from the solution I have (well, some constants differ but its essentially the same), but they do not show how they went from the euqation I gave to the final solution :( So basically, yes, I'm supposed to solve it this way

Answer (score 8):

Starting from $c_1e^x= y+\sqrt{y^2+c_2}$:

$$c_1e^x -y= \sqrt{y^2+c_2}$$
Taking square of both sides

$$c_1e^{2x} + y^2 - 2c_1e^xy = y^2 + c_2$$
Finally it comes to $$y = \frac{c_1^2e^{2x} + c_2}{2c_1e^x}$$

And there is your solution.

Comment: Sigh. I had it in my face all this time. I dunno why, but from first glace I told myself "you cannot get rid of y^2". Guess I am tired. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

**General hint:**

Assume your solution $y(x)$ has a general form like $e^{mx}$ for some $m$. So, set $y=e^{mx}$ and then satisfy it into the ODE to find the probable value of $m$. Note that the [**superposition principle**](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SecondOrderConcepts.aspx) will help us to find the general solution for this ODE.

Comment: Yes, I have seen this mentionned multiples times before. Well, on different sites and all. It brings an interesting subject actually and a question I had about it : on which cases can we apply this assumption? On equations of all forms or... only this particular form?!

Comment: @Yannick: You can use this way for a linear $n$th-order OE with constant coefficients.

Comment: Ohhhh I actually get it now. I shud have read a beeet moar before trying to solve a problem :) Thanks mate

Comment: @Yannick: Thanks. However, other posts completed the answer. :-)

Comment: $\ddot\smile \rightarrow +1$

Comment: @BabakS.: Nice hints +1

Answer (score 5):

One possible way would be , let 
$$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}y(x) + y(x) = g(x) \hspace{1cm} (1) \\  \displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}g(x) - g(x) = 0 \hspace{1cm} (2) $$
first solve $(2)$ for $g(x)$ and then put it's value on $(1)$ and solve $y(x)$ in first order equation.

Equation $(2)$ gives you $\displaystyle g(x) = c_1 e^{x}$ and Equation $(2)$ gives you $\displaystyle y(x) = c_1 e^x + c_2 e^{-x}$. It also gives you an idea that solution will be of form $y(x)=e^{\lambda x}$.

The idea is to represent the equation in terms of operator. i.e. $(D^2 -1) y(x) = 0$. Then $(D^2 - 1)y = (D-1)(D+1)y$, let $(D+1)y = g(x)$ then you have $(D-1)g(x) = 0$ and solve like above.

Comment: I did not think about this one. Very nice. I was actually sticking with solutions similar with what I've read so far, but I guess we can use any substitution. Thanks for this one.

Comment: @Yannick you are welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Your differential equation is a special case of the more general ode $$ay^{''}+by^{'}+cy=0,$$ where $a,b,c$ are real numbers. One way to solve it is by the following two steps:

1. solve $at^2+bt+c=0$ in $t$;
2. check if the roots are either: a) real and different, b) real and repeated or c) complex.

Case a) Let the real and different roots be $t_1,t_2$, the solution is
$$
y(x) = c_1e^{t_1x} + c_2e^{t_2x}.
$$

Case b) Let the real repeated root be $t$, the solution is
$$
y(x) = c_1e^{tx} + c_2xe^{tx}.
$$

Case c) Let the complex roots be ${t_{1,2}} = \lambda  \pm \mu \,i $, the solution is

$$
y\left( x \right) = {c_1}{{e}^{\lambda x}}\cos \left( {\mu \,x} \right) + {c_2}{{e}^{\lambda x}}\sin \left( {\mu \,x} \right).
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With your method you'll have: $y' = p$ and $p' = y$ which is equivalent to
$$
{y' \choose p'} = \overbrace{\pars{\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{array}}}^{\ds{A}}{y \choose p}\quad\imp\quad{y \choose p} = \expo{Ax}{y_{0} \choose p_{0}}
$$
$\ds{A^{2} = \overbrace{\pars{\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}}}^{\ds{I}}.\quad}$ Also $\ds{\pars{\expo{Ax}}' = A\expo{Ax}}$
$\ds{\pars{\expo{Ax}}'' = \expo{Ax}}$, we'll have:
$$
\expo{Ax} = \cosh\pars{x}I + \sinh\pars{x}A 
=
\pars{%
\begin{array}{cc}
\cosh\pars{x} & \sinh\pars{x}
\\
\sinh\pars{x} & \cosh\pars{x}
\end{array}}
$$
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
y = y_{0}\cosh\pars{x} + p_{0}\sinh\pars{x}
=
\overbrace{\half\pars{y_{0} + p_{0}}}^{\ds{\equiv\ c_{1}}}\expo{x}
+
\overbrace{\half\pars{y_{0} - p_{0}}}^{\ds{\equiv\ c_{2}}}\expo{-x}}
$$

Comment: That's pretty fantastic, I'd never thought of exponentiating matrices as a method of solving differential equations!

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy This is a good way to have first order equations. The price to pay is "matrices". Thanks.